# Magento CE 2.2.x - Unable to set attribute set for new product

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I've created a CSV for all the attributes and sets that need to be added and a script to import them. After doing so I'm unable to load the attribute sets in the admin while creating a new product. They (attribute sets) do show up in the list but once selected it returns a 500 followed by a 404.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the `eavSetupFactory` so no strange/weird code

One solution could be to upgrade to 2.3.0 but I currently can't due to a PostNL (shipping module) https://github.com/tig-nl/postnl-magento2/issues/78

#### Preconditions (*)

- Magento CE 2.2.6 without sample data
- Magento CE 2.2.7 without sample data

#### Steps to reproduce (*)

1. Added attributes and set via script

```
    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->setup = $setup;
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        // Create attribute sets
        foreach($this->csv_helper->getAttributeSets() as $attributeSetName) {
            if($eavSetup->getAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $attributeSetName)) {
                continue;
            }

            $this->logger->debug("Creating attribute set: $attributeSetName");            
            $eavSetup->addAttributeSet(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetName
            );
        }

        // Create attributes
        foreach($this->getAttributes() as $attributeData) {
            $attributeCode = $attributeData['code'];
            if ($eavSetup->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeCode)) {
                continue;
            }

            $this->logger->debug("Creating attribute: $attributeCode");

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeCode,
                $this->prepAttributeProperties($attributeData)
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

Upgrade

```
    public function assignAttributeToSet($eavSetup, $attributeSet, $attributeCodes, $attributeGroupCode="General") {

        $entityTypeId = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

        /** @var Set $attributeSet */
        foreach ($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
            $n = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();
            if(empty($n)) {
                continue;
            }

            $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getAttributeGroupId(
                $entityTypeId, 
                $attributeSet->getId(), 
                $attributeGroupCode
            );

            if(!$attributeGroupId) {
                $eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
                    $entityTypeId, 
                    $attributeSet->getId(), 
                    $attributeGroupCode
                );
                $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getAttributeGroupId(
                    $entityTypeId, 
                    $attributeSet->getId(), 
                    $attributeGroupCode
                );
            }

            $attributeId = $eavSetup->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
            $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId, 
                $attributeSet->getId(), 
                $attributeGroupId, 
                $attributeId, 
                null
            );
        }
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->setup = $setup;
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Assign attribute to attribute set
        $attibutesToSets = $this->csv_helper->getAttributesToSets();
        foreach($this->getAttributes() as $attributeData) {
            $attributeCode = $attributeData['code'];
            if(array_key_exists($attributeCode, $attibutesToSets)) {

                foreach($attibutesToSets[$attributeCode] as $attributeSetName) {                
                    if(!$attributeData['group'] || empty($attributeData['group'])) {
                        $this->logger->error("Group is empty for attribute '$attributeCode'");
                        continue;
                    }
                    $this->logger->debug("Assigning '$attributeCode' to $attributeSetName");
                    $this->assignAttributeToSet(
                        $eavSetup, 
                        $this->getAttributeSetByName($attributeSetName), 
                        array($attributeCode), 
                        $attributeData['group']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

2. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
4. `bin/magento cache:flush`
5. open admin
6. Validate the attribute set via `admin/catalog/product_set/index`

[image]

6. Add simple product
7. select attribute set

#### Expected result (*)

1. attributes to add new product

#### Actual result (*)

1. [image]
2. `POST /admin_/catalog/product/reload/type/simple/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/9/key/XXX/?set=undefined&isAjax=true`
3. `POST /admin_/catalog/product/reload/type/simple/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/12/key/XXXXX/?set=&isAjax=true`

```
    Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::mergeMetadataElement() must be of the type array, null given, called in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 379 and defined in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:329
    Stack trace:
    #0 vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(379): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataElement(Array, 'configurableExi...', NULL, false)
    #1 vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(404): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
    #2 vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(404): Magento\Framework\Vi in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 329
```

Following the code:

```
/**
 * Merge metadata item to components
 *
 * @param array $bundleComponents
 * @param array $metadata
 * @param bool $reverseMerge
 * @return array
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
protected function mergeMetadataItem(array $bundleComponents, array $metadata, $reverseMerge = false)
{
    foreach ($metadata as $name => $data) {
        $selfData = $data;
        if (isset($selfData['children'])) {
            unset($selfData['children']);
        }

        list($bundleComponents, $isMerged) = $this->mergeMetadataElement(
            $bundleComponents,
            $name,
            $selfData,
            $reverseMerge
        );
```

the `$name` in this case is `configurableExistingAttributeSetId`, `$selfData` is `NULL`

#### Related info

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19722 (this issue)
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15117
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by

```
$eavSetup->addAttributeSet(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetName
);
```

This creates an actual empty attribute set without the required base attributes causing the backend to fail.

I've replaced it with the following:

```
public function __construct(
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetCollectionFactory $attributeSetCollectionFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, 
    CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    CsvHelper $csv_helper
) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetCollectionFactory = $attributeSetCollectionFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
    $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->csv_helper = $csv_helper;
}

/**
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    // $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $eavSetup = $objectManager->create('X043\ProductInfo\Setup\MySetup', array());

    $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

    $i = 200;
    // Create attribute sets
    foreach($this->csv_helper->getAttributeSets() as $attributeSetName) {
        $i++;
        if($eavSetup->getAttributeSet(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $attributeSetName))
            continue;

        $this->logger->debug("Creating attribute set: $attributeSetName");            
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => $attributeSetName,
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => $i,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();   
    }

    // Create attributes
    foreach($this->getAttributes() as $attributeData) {
        $attributeCode = $attributeData['code'];
        if ($eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode))
            continue;

        $this->logger->debug("Creating attribute: $attributeCode");
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeCode,
            $this->prepAttributeProperties($attributeData)
        );
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: Exactly i am getting the same error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334, where i can update the above code. Thanks @PvdL